# VBA Excel Dictionary inside Dictionary late binding

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

The following code fails on the debug statement

```
Sub Tets()
Dim cl_data As Object
Set cl_data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim row As Object

Dim irow As Long
For irow = 11 To 12
    Set row = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With row
        row.Add "YN", Cells(irow, 2).Value
        row.Add "Comment", Cells(irow, 3).Value
    End With
    cl_data.Add Cells(irow, 1).Value, row
Next irow
Debug.Print cl_data(CStr(Cells(irow, 1)))("YN")
End Sub
```

[image]

I am traying to save data from columns A, B and C. The "outer dictionary is supposed to have the value from column A as key, inside is another dictionary with data from column b saved with key "YN" and data from column c saved with key "Comment".

Comment: You also want keys exists test btw: If Not cl_data.exists(Cells(irow, 1).Value) Then

Comment: Please indicate which line occurs. Assume that is 13 type mismatch?

Comment: I don't have the same error as you (I got a 457 error) which says that you have a key issue. A dictionary key is unique for the reason as it is associate to an item, it needs to be unique. In your code, when you add an element to cl_data, you add twice the same value (Cells(irow, 1))

Comment: @Chris - it depends on what is in A11:A12 on the activesheet.

Comment: @Jeeped yup I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that after your loop.

```
For irow = 11 To 12
     '…
Next irow
```

The `Debug.Print irow` returns `13`. And this is not in your dictionary because you read only rows `11` and `12`.

Comment: Such a simple answer and just a stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try *row* as an array of objects and reset irow to something within the bounds after exiting the loop.

```
Sub Tets()

    Dim irow As Long, cl_data As Object, row(11 To 12) As Object

    Set cl_data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For irow = 11 To 12
        Set row(irow) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With row(irow)
            .Add "YN", Cells(irow, 2).Value
            .Add "Comment", Cells(irow, 3).Value
        End With
        cl_data.Add Key:=Cells(irow, 1).Value, Item:=row(irow)
    Next irow

    irow = 11
    Debug.Print cl_data(CStr(Cells(irow, 1)))("YN")
    irow = 12
    Debug.Print cl_data(CStr(Cells(irow, 1)))("YN")

End Sub
```

Comment: For my interest why did you declare `row` as an array? For me it works without an array too. Any reason I missed here?

Comment: I suppose that redoing the CreateObject on the second pass would extinguish the first after making a copy as the item of the array but I wasn't eager to chance it for the sake of an extra array element. It may not be required but the code ran through on the first try so I didn't remove it.

Comment: Thx for clarification.